How to check if a value from one column is repeated in all other columns in R?
I have a dataset with multiple columns that contains information from different schools. I am standardizing all the information, so all schools display the same information. To do so, I am trying to identify if the same information is displayed in all columns and identify which column and row does not display the same information.
Suppose I have the following dataset:
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"),
                 col2 = c("B", "A", "C", "F", "E", NA),
                 col3 = c("C", "B", "A", "F", "G", "D"))

Which gives me the following dataframe:
  col1 col2 col3
1    A    B    C
2    B    A    B
3    C    C    A
4    D    F    F
5    E    E    G
6    F <NA>    D

In this hypothetical dataframe I created, I intentionally added a missing value in col2 and a unique value G in col3.
Using the column col1 as a benchmark, is there a smart and elegant way can I identify which is the value missing in col2, col3, and how can I identify G as a unique value in column col3?
Quick clarification. If we hold col1 as the comparison benchmark, the letter D is missing in col2 and the letter E is missing in col3. Is there an easy way to get this?
Also, in col3 there is a unique value G that is not contained in col1. I would like to find a way that point to this too.
Hopefully this is not confusing. Let me know if you need more clarification.

What output do you want?

If we take column col1 as a benchmark, the letter D is missing in col2 and the letter E is missing in col3. I would like a way to get that. Additionally, G is a unique value in col3, and is not contained in col1. Maybe I should clarity this in the question.

Maybe something like this?
lapply(df[-1], \(x) {
  list(extra = setdiff(x, df$col1), absent = setdiff(df$col1, x))
})
# $col2
# $col2$extra
# [1] NA
# 
# $col2$absent
# [1] "D"
# 
# 
# $col3
# $col3$extra
# [1] "G"
# 
# $col3$absent
# [1] "E"


This works !! Let me test this code in my real data. Thank you so much, Gregor!

The code seems to be running, but it does not display the results like yours. Is there an extra step to display it?

Never mind, my RStudio was bugged. It is displaying the results.

It works on my real data! Thank you so much!

Hey Gregor! Do you know resources like books or website that teach the type of code you used? I wish I knew more about R Base codes.

I learn most of what I know reading and answering questions on Stack Overflow. For base R in particular, I would highly recommend The R Inferno.
